# In Rails, if "before_filter :login_required" works, then why will adding "login_required" to an action not work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If using

```
before_filter :login_required
```

works, for all actions of a controller, but if I comment that line out, and just do it like so:

```
def index
  login_required
    [...]
end
```

then the server complains that it can only render or redirect once per action.  I thought using a before filter is the same as adding that method like above.  Please explain.

Answer (score 2):

> before_filter and around_filter may
>   halt the request before a controller
>   action is run. This is useful, for
>   example, to deny access to
>   unauthenticated users or to redirect
>   from HTTP to HTTPS. Simply call render
>   or redirect. After filters will not be
>   executed if the filter chain is
>   halted.

This is from the [rails API](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html)(Filter Chain Halting). So, if in a filter, if a render or redirect happens, the filter chain halts and the rest code will not be executed. So, the error will not happen in this case. But when you call the method directly, the code after the method call will also be executed and therefore, the error 'render or redirect once per action' happens.

Comment: if you decide to call it in the action instead, then how would that be done?

Comment: @動靜能量 then you have to pass a flag from `login_required` if the redirect happens in the login_required and call `return` in the `index` method if the flag is set